# I can't render a scene with GPU Compute using intel Iris GPU

Tags: gpu

I have a MacbookPro with the following specs:

Processor: 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory: 8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB

SO my problem is I have created my first animation scene and I want to render a picture of it and see what it will look like. (I am following Black Plasma Studios tutorial which is very detailed and easy to follow.) I have all the settings correct and I render it with the GPU but when I do it says OpenCL build failed: errors in console
Please tell me what I need to do I really want my animations to render fast.
Thank You
BenCosmos

Comment: As far as I know Intel Iris GPUs are not supported. See: https://developer.blender.org/T47801

Comment: Wow so basically I can never have a fast rendered animation. D:

Comment: Rip me. But thank you cegaton! You probably saved me a lot of trouble